# Getting Average in a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. I want to take average, max, min document value in a whole collection. I was able to calculate max and min but don't know how to calculate average or how to start it.

This is how I calculated max.

```
db.mytable.find({},{"abc":1}).sort({"abc":-1}).limit(1);
```

Comment: check [mongo groups operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the average for the whole collection, use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** with the **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)** pipeline operator where you can specify an `_id` value of null to calculate the accumulated average value for all the input documents as a whole:

```
db.mytable.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": { 
            "_id": null, 
            "avg": { "$avg": "$abc" } 
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: max and min are working but avg is always = 0. @chridam

Comment: @AmanjotKaur Note that `$avg` ignores non-numeric values, maybe the `abc` field is non-numeric?

Comment: Thanks. I got It. Can you refer me where can I study mongoDb better

Comment: You could go to the [**MongoDB Wiki page**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mongodb/info) here on SO for an exhaustive list of resources but some good places to start with are the [**MongoDB manual**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/), [**MongoDB tutorials**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/), [**MongoDB University courses**](https://university.mongodb.com/) and [**MongoDB YouTube Channel**](https://www.youtube.com/user/MongoDB/playlists).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to investigate the [Aggregation Framework](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/aggregation-framework-0) for this:

For the mean average you can use:

```
db.mytable.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group: { _id: "$abc", avg: { $avg: "$to_average" } }
    }
  ]
);
```

You can also use the aggregation framework for max, e.g.

```
db.mytable.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group: { _id: "$abc", max: { $max: "$to_get_max_for" } }
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: Using aggregation framework, i get avg, max , min in group by. I dont want to use group by @jabclab. I simply want just average of the whole collection. like avg() function of Mysql